# Is it possible to call a function within qx?

Tags: perl, qx

Here's a bit of Perl code that does what I want:

```
 my $value  = get_value();
 my $result = qx(some-shell-command $value);

 sub get_value {
   ...
   return ...
 }
```

Is it possible to achieve the same effect without using `$value`? Something like

```
my $result = qx (some-shell-command . ' '. get_value());
```

I know why the second approach doesn't work, it's just to demonstrate the idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
my $result = qx(some-shell-command  @{[ get_value() ]});

# or dereferencing single scalar value 
# (last one from get_value if it returns more than one)
my $result = qx(some-shell-command  ${ \get_value() });
```

but I would rather use your first option.

*Explanation:* perl arrays interpolate inside `""`, `qx()`, etc.

Above is array reference `[]` holding result of function, being dereferenced by `@{}`, and interpolated inside `qx()`.

Comment: Thanks for a clever solution. I am with you, though, I will still be using $value.

Comment: Does this work because `qx` expects `STDIN` to be a list? But even if `get_value()` returns a LIST, we still need `[ ]` (anonymous list/array) which we then dereference to feed to the first element of `qx` ... Why is that step needed? Does this syntax somehow make everything into one list inside of the `qx` delimitters?

Comment: @G.Cito `perl -e 'print qx( echo @{[ 3..7 ]} )'` `qx` takes string, and `@{}` interpolates mentioned array.

Comment: ah OK of course it's needed to *interpolate* whatever is in the anon array list. In other words: it's an example of the `@{[ ]}` or ["Babycart" list interpolation operator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perlsecret/lib/perlsecret.pod#Baby_cart) in action!  +1 Thanks for the explanation :-)

Comment: @salva tnx for comment.

Answer (score 2):

Backticks and [`qx`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qx.html) are equivalent to the builtin [`readpipe`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readpipe.html) function, so you could explicitly use that:

```
$result = readpipe("some-shell-command " . get_value());
```

Comment: Cool, learned something new.  Mostly try for pure perl solutions instead of shelling things out, but this is nice to know. +1